# Merge properties of one Json schema in another Json schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a schema whose properties I have to merge in another schema. Suppose following is the schema whose properties have to be included:

```
{"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
"title": "native",
"type": "object",
"required": ["executable"],
"properties":
{
  "job_name":
  {
    "type":"string",
    "dname": "job name"
  },
  "executable":
  {
    "type":"string",
    "dname":"server",
    "description": "server name"
  }
}}
```

The schema that includes the above schema is of the form:

```
{"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
"title": "application",
"type": "object",
"required": ["app_name"],
"properties":
{
  "app_name":
  {
    "type":"string",
    "dname": "app name"
  }
}}
```

I want to merge the properties of first schema in the second one so that the second one looks like :

```
{"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
"title": "native",
"type": "object",
"required": ["executable","app_name"],
"properties":
{
  "job_name":
  {
    "type":"string",
    "dname": "job name"
  },
  "executable":
  {
    "type":"string",
    "dname":"server",
    "description": "server name"
  }
  "app_name":
  {
    "type":"string",
    "dname": "app name"
  }
}}
```

Also, the "required" field gets added to the second schema.
Is there a way it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could extend one schema in another using 'extends' keyword as follows :

- Define the first schema in the same file in the definitions (I hope it can be another json schema file as well) and extend it in another schema.

  ```
  "definitions" : {
   "argumentBaseType":{
   "required": ["executable"],
   "properties":
   {
    "job_name":
    {
     "type":"string",
     "dname": "job name"
    },
   "executable":
   {
    "type":"string",
    "dname":"server",
    "description": "server name"
   }
  }
  }
  "properties":
  {
  {
   Argument1 : {
    "extends" : {
      "$ref" : "#/definitions/argumentBaseType"
    },
    "app_name":
    {
     "type":"string",
     "dname": "app name"
    }
   }}
  ```

Comment: IIRIC, there is no `extends` keyword in the JSON Schema. Where does it come from?

Comment: @Onkeltem, looks like there was in draft 3, removed in draft 4: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-fge-json-schema-validation-00#appendix-A

Answer (score 4):

You can't merge schemas, but you can use `allOf` to require that a document validates against both schemas.  It's not the same as merge, but it will work for the case you presented.

```
{
  "allOf": [
    { ... schema1 ... },
    { ... schema2 ... }
  ]
}
```